# How to upload files using graphql-java on a netty server?

Tags: graphql, netty, graphql-java, spring-graphql

Most of the solutions I found on this topic use some kind of a servlet framework.
How do we achieve this in a reactive app running on netty server?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported by the Spring GraphQL project but is being considered under the following issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/issues/69

GraphQL doesn't support binary data, so some applications handle uploads outside of GraphQL.